# How to form idmodel from iddata in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to convert an iddata object into idmodel. The iddata is formed of a time series 100*19(multiple output) matrix. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the data itself ,generate a transfer function,from transfer function , get num, den using tfdata command. use tf2zp to get poles and zeros.use arx command and generate the model